# Retaining values in Silverlight App on exit

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-desktop-gadgets

Just as it says in the title of this question, I am trying to retain a Timespan value when the application is closed. Here's the situation...I am writing a Windows gadget, everytime the flyout window is closed it destroys it, and the Timespan value along with it. I want it so each time the flyout window is closed it retains this value how would this be accomplished?

The code of what I'm currently doing is below.

```
SilverlightGadgetUtilities.Stopwatch watch = new SilverlightGadgetUtilities.Stopwatch();

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        watch.currentTime();
        this.RootVisual = new Page();

    }

    private void Application_Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        watch.currentTime();
    }
```

And this is in my Stopwatch class:

```
    public TimeSpan? currentTime()
    {
        current = Elapsed;
        return current;
    }

    public TimeSpan? Elapsed
    {
        get
        {
            return new TimeSpan(this.GetElapsedDateTimeTicks() * 10000000);
        }
    }
```

Where `GetElapsedDateTimeTicks()` is using `DateTime.Now.Second()` for the timing.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store data in your application's isolated storage settings and retrieve it on launch.

Here is an example of storing the information in IsolatedStorageSettings:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("MySettingName", MySetting);
```

You would then retrieve it using:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["MySettingName"];
```

IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings acts very much like a dictionary. You should check to see if there is already a setting of that name being stored, and if so, either remove it, or overwrite it. Overwriting it could be done like so:

```
if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("MySettingName"))
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("MySettingName", MySetting);
else
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["MySettingName"] = MySetting;
```

The code to remove and re-add would be similar, except swapping the else block for:

```
else
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("MySettingName");
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("MySettingName", MySetting);
}
```

Comment: I get an error 'an item with the same key has already been added' do I need to instantiate a new one before use?

Comment: Try IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationsSettings["MySettingName"] = MySetting; instead. On retrieval make sure it exists before you try to access it. Something like:            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("MySettingName"))
            { var setting = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["MySettingName"]; 
            }

Comment: Another question, how would I have the program pick up from where it left off if say it crashes or someone closes it? I mean instead of starting the timer over it just continues from the saved time.

Comment: For someone closing it, you could save to the IsolatedStorageSettings in the Application_Exit event handler. As far as saving the data on program crashes...you might potentially still be able to save data in the case of an unhandled exception by subscribing to the Application_UnhandledException event handler. More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.unhandledexception(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I actually switched all of this over to a WPF Application instead, a little easier to work with lol. I did end up using Isolated Storage there as well, thanks for the help!